# Detect other running iOS app using systcl

Tags: objective-c, ios, sysctl

I use sysctl () function to get the process list, but is there a way to detect currently running app? My app is location based app and it runs in the background. I want to detect which app is running in foreground at certain time intervals. Is this possible at all?

I understand this kind of app behavior is forbidden by apple but I still like to try this.

Comment: Did you figure out this problem? I'm actually trying to solve the same issue right now. I've been looking for a solution for a week now.

Comment: I couldn't figure this out. All I could able to get is get a list of all running applications. Foreground and background not killed tasks.

Comment: Yes, same here. I couldn't get the the one that;s in the foreground.